# Does Mysql execute statement synchronously in one connection?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, servlets, database-connection

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root", "password");
```

Let's say in Java, we can create a mysql connection via the code above. From the `connection` object, we can create few `statement` objects as below:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
```

I would like to know, if we execute those `statement` object (by calling `statement.executeQuery`) in different threads, will they execute synchronously or asynchronously in Mysql database? Because what I know is, one connection in mysql will be handled as one thread, so my thinking is, all the statements that are created by that connection will schedule in its queue. Am I correct?

So, if I have a `servlet` like below:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root", "password");  


   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

    statement = connection.createStatement();
   }
}
```

From the code above, if there are more than one user connect to the `servlet` at the same time, will they block each other because the statement cannot execute parallel at the same time? So, they have to wait previous statement finish executing before their turn take on? Any way to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: First, you won't be able to use `getConnection` in the field initialization. Second, use a connection pool and create and use one statement per connection.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis even if you do this, OP's not in the right approach.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza In what sense?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the `Connection` object must be in atomic operations, this means it should not be shared among multiple threads, which is indeed wrong. You can find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/1065197, specifically in the **Threadsafety** section (emphasys taken from BalusC's answer).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What I meant with the connection pool comment was to acquire and use the connection in the handler method (doGet, doPost, etc.). Unless OP shares that `Connection` object in there, they will be fine.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes I agree with that part, but `Connection` **must not** be a field of a Servlet, instead a local variable in the necessary method (not even in the `doGet` nor `doPost` methods =\\).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza We're on the same page. And you've made it clearer for OP!

Comment: HI, @SotiriosDelimanolis, can tell why "you won't be able to use getConnection in the field initialization"?

Comment: @GMsoF Try it and see. `DriverManager#getConnection()` is declared as throwing an `SQLException`. A thrown checked exception cannot be handled by the default no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because what I know is, one connection in mysql will be handled as one thread, so my thinking is, all the statements that are created by that connection will schedule in its queue.

You should *not* hold a database connection open to the database.  You should use a connection pool like [Apache's DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and get a connection, execute your query or other SQL, and then release the connection to the pool.

> if there are more than one user connect to the servlet at the same time, will they block each other because the statement cannot execute parallel at the same time? So, they have to wait previous statement finish executing before their turn take on?

Right.  If you have one user making a database transaction, another thread cannot use the same connection to the database at the same time.

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
     Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("j...");
```

Yeah, you should *not* create a connection as a field to your servlet class like this.  It will open a TCP connection to the database and hold it for the life of your application.  These connections sometimes time out or are closed because of network issues so need to be kept alive and on occasion reopened.  All of this is handled by DBCP or other connection pools.

Comment: +1. IMO would change the *should not create a connection like this* for a *must not*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multithreading then each thread should have its own connection. If threads share connections then it becomes a single threaded application as threads will not be able to work simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Besides weather you are able to create a `connection` like that or not,Servlet  instance member's  are not thread-safe.So when you use `connection` it in servelt as  instance member,definitley you are inviting problems.

Go for a connection pool, and make a instance for thread.